# Checking a Condition on all rows of a child table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables for example:

**Tasks** table:

```
TaskID , TaskName
```

and then **TaskDetails** table:

```
TaskDetailsID, TaskID, CompletionDate
```

I want to write a query to give me all the tasks that all of their task details have been completed in the last 10 days.

How can I write such a query? I don't want to use `cursors` and I tried using `INNER JOIN` but it is returning too many records. So I think something else is needed but not sure what it is.

Comment: You should tag RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Can there be incomplete tasks, i.e. rows with `CompletionDate` set to NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this if you need more column details

```
SELECT T.Task_Name,
       TMP.TaskDetailsID, 
       TMP.TaskID,
       TMP.CompletionDate
  FROM (SELECT TD.*,
               MIN(CompletionDate) OVER
                 ( PARTITION BY TaskID ) mn_CompDate
          FROM Task_Details TD
       ) TMP
 INNER
  JOIN Task T
    ON TMP.taskID = T.taskID
 WHERE TMP.mn_CompDate >= dateadd(day, -10, getdate());
```

Comment: What is the job of ""MIN" for in that query?

Comment: Get the earliest completion date for a task it

Comment: Why do I need the earliest?

Comment: Depends. What do you mean by "all task details have been completed in the last 10 days"? If you mean, there is no task detail completed before 10 days ago, that's why you need it. If you mean something else, sample data and expected result would clear up the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, I mean only find tasks that ALL of their task details have been completed in the last 10 days .. so for example if a task has three task details, all of them are completed too BUT one of them has a completion date that goes back to three months ago, then we do NOT want to return this Task as a result

Comment: Okay, in that case the minimum date would be 3 months ago and it'd get dropped here WHERE TMP.mn_CompDate >= dateadd(day, -10, getdate());

Answer (score 1):

Try this for SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TaskDetails
                 WHERE t.TaskID = TaskID
                 AND CompletionDate < DATEADD(DAY, -10, GETDATE()))
```

or this, for MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TaskDetails
                 WHERE t.TaskID = TaskID
                 AND CompletionDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -10 DAY))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use aggregation and `having`:

```
select td.taskid
from taskdetails td
group by td.taskid
having min(td.completiondate) >= dateadd(day, -10, getdate());
```

Comment: so no use of "Tasks" table - the parent - needed ?

Comment: also says wrong syntx because CompletionDate is in the having but not in the GroupBy

Comment: @Bohn . . . That makes no sense.  `CompletionDate` is the argument to an aggregation function.  It is fine in the `group by`.  This is a simple solution to the question.